# Duplicate column via adding a new row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What formula can I use in Google Sheets to achieve this?

```
December 26, 2018

December 24, 2018
```

to

```
December 26, 2018

December 26, 2018

December 24, 2018

December 24, 2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(TO_DATE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(
 TO_TEXT(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))&"♠"), 2), , 999^99), "♠")), "mmmm dd, yyyy")))
```

[image: 0]